How can I use an artifact from gitlab in my markdown in gitlab
I can already produce a graph from some data uploaded to my repository in gitlab using the inbuilt gitlab-ci and python.
I wish to be able to display the png's that I get as artifacts in the .md documents in my repository.
I have tried to do:
![](image2.png)

and
![](COMPLETE_URL)

with the complete url to the previous artifact. This does not work. There is no image displayed and the page is just blank. The first just does not work and the second might work but since the url changes between pushes there is no way of knowing.
How do I get my artifact png to display in my .md file when I open it in gitlab.

Can you provide the structure of your code ?
Because the first option work
